# Consecutive Red Candles then Consecutive green candles

Tags: pine-script

I want to mark (plotshape) two consecutive red candles. Then two Consecutive green candles, after that again two consecutive red candles then two consecutive green candles. please see the picture, I need a pattern like this in pine script.

[image: This is plotting I need please]

```
 //@version=4
study(title="Highlight red candles", overlay=true)

twoRedCandles = (close[1] < open[1]) and (close < open)

twoGreenCandles = (close[1] > open[1]) and (close > open)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `var` counter to count if there are consecutive green/red bars.

Reset this counter when the bar is of opposite color or if it reaches to number you are looking for.

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © vitruvius

//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

green_th = input.int(2)
red_th = input.int(3)

is_green = close > open
is_red = not is_green

var cnt_green = 0
var cnt_red = 0

cnt_green := is_green ? cnt_green + 1 : 0
cnt_red := is_red ? cnt_red + 1 : 0

is_green_th_hit = cnt_green == green_th
is_red_th_hit = cnt_red == red_th

cnt_green := is_green_th_hit ? 0 : cnt_green
cnt_red := is_red_th_hit ? 0 : cnt_red

plotshape(is_green_th_hit, "G", shape.triangleup, location.belowbar, color.green)
plotshape(is_red_th_hit, "R", shape.triangledown, location.abovebar, color.red)
```

[image]

## Edit

You can use another `var` to see if the last one was a green formation.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

green_th = input.int(2)
red_th = input.int(3)

is_green = close > open
is_red = not is_green

var last_one_was_green = false
var cnt_green = 0
var cnt_red = 0

cnt_green := is_green ? cnt_green + 1 : 0
cnt_red := is_red ? cnt_red + 1 : 0

is_green_th_hit = not last_one_was_green and (cnt_green == green_th)
is_red_th_hit = last_one_was_green and (cnt_red == red_th)

last_one_was_green := is_green_th_hit ? true : is_red_th_hit ? false : last_one_was_green
cnt_green := is_green_th_hit ? 0 : cnt_green
cnt_red := is_red_th_hit ? 0 : cnt_red

plotshape(is_green_th_hit, "G", shape.triangleup, location.belowbar, color.green)
plotshape(is_red_th_hit, "R", shape.triangledown, location.abovebar, color.red)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but my question is if we count two consecutive green candles, then it should look for only next two consecutive red candle. after that again two consecutive green candle . *A two consecutive green candles followed by next two consecutive red candle. eg: GG---RR---GG--RR--GG ( should not mark GG...GG..GG..RR..RR etc ). please 
see the picture in link,  the X marked candles should avoid means after two consecutive green then it should look for only next two reds 
 https://ibb.co/JmdzM3C

@vitruvius

Comment: Please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

After 2 consecutive red candles, next is 2 consecutive green candles
Although @vitruvius tried but the edit is false. Editor amend the arrow pointing at 3 red candle bars to 2